# Speech flow with contracted "did"

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

I'm asking this because I'm curious to know the way native speekers say this:

- Where did you get this.

In this sentence when we contract the "**did**" in speech do we stress the word that precedes it or the one that follows it?

I mean do we say "**Where'd you get this?**" or we say "**Where d'you get this?**".

This also implies other words like **what**,**how**,**when** and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I mean do we say **"Where'd you get this?"** or we say **"Where d'you get this?"**.`

There is a time difference between the two:

> Where'd you get this?

is past tense, and means "Where **did** you get this."

> Where d'you get this?

is present tense, and means "Where **do** you get this?"

Comment: In my neck of the woods, there's a difference in pronunciation.  With "where'd you" there is a  /dʒ/ sound as in the word "edge" which is not present in "Where d'you"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Same here, and *d'you* has a y-glide after the initial *d* resolving into the final vowel sound.

Answer (score 0):

"Where'd you get this?" is how I would say it. "Where d'you get this?" makes me have to pause a little and causes a dip in the intonation of "d'you". Same with what,how,when - I would always add the 'd to the end and not before the next word. If you want to use "do" instead, it might end up sounding more similar to the second option but I would always explicitly say "do" and not "d'you".

Comment: **D'you** sounds like **dew** or **due** when I pronoune it.

Comment: @SovereignSun I'd pronounce it as **dyu** or **dyoo**. I'm from around the Detroit, MI area for reference.

Comment: @bhow I don't know about SovereignSun, but for me, "due" and "dew" both sound like "dyu" or "dyoo" (as does "d'you").